# Way to print the keyboard shortcut to the screen if I use the manual way to perform an action instead of the keyboard shortcut.?

Tags: add-on, shortcut

I decided to learn all blender keyboard shortcut and I wondered wether are there a way to print the keyboard shortcut to the screen if I use the manual way to perform an action.

So for example if I switch to edit mode using the header it will print TAB or something like that.

Does anyone knows an addon or an option for this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think, such an add on can be done in python.

Most menu shortcuts are written on the right side of the menu item.

[image]

---

To ascertain other shortcuts, do the following.

1. Hover over the menu item. You will see the python command. Make a note of the command after *bpy.ops*. In this case **object.edit_mode**.
   [image]
2. Open the *User Preferences* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> and go to the **Input** tab. Type the command in the searchbar and hotkey entries will be shown.
   [image]